# Autocomplete com pesquisa por id e nome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, autocompletar

Como posso fazer um autocomplete com pesquisa em duas colunas da base de dados?

Já dei uma vista de olhos em vários exemplos, e vi um que utiliza um género de grid, é algo do género `$("#seletor").combogrid(...)`.

Eu já consegui implementar o meu autocomplete mas só faz a pesquisa por nome do Artigo e eu gostava que também fizesse a pesquisa pelo id.

**HTML**

```
<input class="codigo autoC" type="text" placeholder="Nome ou Código do Artigo">
```

**JQUERY**

```
//Pedido ajax que retorna a lista dos artigos   

    myJSRoutes.controllers.c_base.c_artigos.ArtigoController.getAllArtigos().ajax({
       success: function (data) {
         if (data.length > 0) {
           $.each(data, function (key, value) {
             artigos.push(value.nome);
           });
         }
       }
    })

//AUTOCOMPLETE
    $(document).on('click', '.autoC', function () {
        $(".autoC").autocomplete({
            source: artigos,
            //REMOVE UM SPAN ADICIONADO AUTOMATICAMENTE AO GERAR O AUTOCOMPLETE
            create: function (e) {
                $(this).prev('.ui-helper-hidden-accessible').remove();
            }
        });
    })
```

Alguma sugestão de como pesquisar por id e nome?

Comment: Poderia por favor colocar o código do seu filtro?

Comment: Desculpe não percebi a questão. Tudo o que tenho relacionado com o meu autocomplete está na questão. Talvez falte alguma coisa mas...é tudo o que tenho no meu código. Desde já obrigado